# How do i use third party Go libraries with google app engine's development server?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

In one of my .go files I have:

```
import (
  ...
  "github.com/stripe/stripe-go"
  "appengine"
  "appengine/datastore"
)
```

But when i run `dev_appserver.py app.yaml` I get the following error:

```
Can't find package "github.com/stripe/stripe-go" in $GOPATH
```

I've tried running `go get github.com/stripe/stripe-go` which I can see successfully installs to `~/go/src/github.com/stripe/stripe-go` but the GAE dev server doesn't seem to look at that path for some reason.

`gcloud app deploy` works just fine, for what it's worth.

Comment: Did you try vendoring the dependency?

Comment: @mkopriva No, but thanks for the tip! If that works, please put as an answer so i can vote and mark as success, so you get the "points" :)

Comment: Vendoring doesn't seem to work well with the dev app server. However, this workaround seems to do the trick for dev mode:

    `cd ~/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/goroot-1.8/src`
    `ln -s ~/go/src/github.com github.com`

That way any libraries from github.com that are installed with a vanilla `go get foolibrary` seem to work.

Comment: So you're saying that adding a `/vendor` folder to your project's root and putting the dependencies there doesn't work? Genuinely curious as I am not a GAE user myself... The error message you have in your question, is it the full message? Did the message change after adding the vendor folder?

Comment: I'm asking because the go tool will ouput a slightly different error if the vendor folder is present as opposed to when it's not. It adds a line that indicates that it was looking for the dependency in the vendor folder first and then in the GOPATH... see this example: https://imgur.com/a/K4ZVW

Comment: @mkopriva Yes, adding the dependencies into a /vendor folder does not work unfortunately. GAE is quite odd.

Answer (score 2):

Got the same error while testing the import "github.com/stripe/stripe-go" and fixed it by following the steps [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/using-go-libraries) "EDIT":

```
export GOPATH=/home/user/go_project
```

And a sample.go file in the example app's directory contains the following import statement:

```
import (
  ...
  "github.com/stripe/stripe-go"
  "appengine"
  "appengine/datastore"
)
```

Then the gcloud tool will look for the "stripe/stripe-go" package in the following location when you run or deploy the app:

```
/home/user/go_project/src/stripe/stripe-go
```

Once the above is done, the devserver should look at the proper path after you've run "go get github.com/my_repo/packagename". hope it helps